# What should I look for when building a malware lab on a budget?

Tags: malware

What should I look for when building a malware lab on a budget?  $800 USD or less. I'm talking about hardware and virtualization capabilities, or alternatives (e.g. FOG Server).  Not user programs that load the actual malware for analysis (Olly, IDA, etc.).

ESXi seems popular with virtualization, but does that have any advantages over a malware lab with VirtualBox, aside from performance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a product recommendation. Have a look at why [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are off-topic.

Comment: Please raise any concerns you may have regarding the site on [meta]. The purpose of the meta site is to discuss exactly such issues.

Answer (score 2):

ESXi can be useful if you want to try the sample on a number of systems. And let it run for a while. Due to TimeLocks, timebomb etc etc.

I'd go for a good Laptop(16GB RAM sort of thing) and Vmware workstation / virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks.  Does the free version of ESXi support snapshots?  I plan on having the infected VM, Security Onion VM, Remnux VM, and a firewall VM to block some traffic route the allowed through Tor.  Is 16 GB RAM enough to run those VMs at the same time?

Comment: Not sure about the snapshots, I do think it does. And 16 MB Ram is more than enough. REMNUX runs fine with 512Mb

Comment: Yes to both, generally. ESX(i) can snap though I'm not certain about cloning.

Comment: What kind of hard drive am I going to need?  If I use VirtualBox there will be my main OS, and 4 or more VMs running at the same time.  Am I going to need an SSD for the VMs?

Comment: I am afraid you won't be able to find quad core 16Gb laptop with SSD drive for around $800 you wanted to spend.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking of a desktop.  Would I likely need a SSD?  Apparently Windows 7 Home Premium only supports 16 GB of RAM so Microsoft can get every dollar they can out of us.  :(